# How to read off the facets of polytopes from their Gale diagrams and affine Gale diagrams?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polytopes, discrete-geometry

We have this theorem:

> Let $P = conv(V) \subset \mathbb{R}^d $ be a d-polytope. Let B be the Gale transform of $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$. Then $conv\{v_j|j \in J\}$ is a face of P iff either $J=[n]$ or $0 \in relint(conv\{b_k|k \not\in J\}) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-d-1} $

When it comes to actual problems that I want to solve by hand, such as these two:

[image]

the Gale diagram (for the first problem) makes it hard to read off the facets.

[image]

Are there any other ways to do it by hand?

Comment: If you're troubled by how condensed the drawing is, consider rescaling the $x$ axis. That won't change convex hulls and will be easier to read.

Comment: That's a great idea. Thanks! But I wonder if there is a better way to do these kinds of exercise (listing out facets, circuits, etc.), since this method takes lots of time to check, and it is still prone to leaving out or double-counting elements.

Comment: I know you said you wanted it by hand, but this is a perfect problem for some linear programming and a little python script :)